# SQL query with SubQuery on the relation fields by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to receive a data object country. An object country has the following attributes (id, continent_id, language_id).

```
Table countries {
  id, name, continent_id, language_id
}

Table continents {
  id, name
}

Table languages {
  id, name
}
```

Instead of getting a DataObject containing only the `continent_id` and `language_id`, I want to get the name of the continent and the language. Like that:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: Germany,
  continent_id: 1,
  language_id: 1,
  continent: "europe", // new field
  language: "german" // new field
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to join the two additional tables to the man countries

If every country has only one language, this will be enough to `INNER JOIN` them.

with multiply languages, you need to `GROUP BY` and use `GROUP_CONCAT` or the languages

```
SELECT
    countr.id, contr.name, continent_id, language_id 
    , co.name as continent
    , lang.name as language
FROM countries  countr 
INNER JOIN continents co ON contr.continent_id = co.id
INNER JOIN languages  lang ON lang.id = contr.language_id
```

If a country has multiple languages

```
SELECT
    countr.id, contr.name, continent_id, language_id 
    , co.name as continent
    , GROUP_CONCAT(lang.name) as languages
FROM countries  countr 
INNER JOIN continents co ON contr.continent_id = co.id
INNER JOIN languages  lang ON lang.id = contr.language_id 
GROUP BY countr.id, contr.name, continent_id, language_id,co.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will test it. In the meantime I had also made a request with two JOINS. I'm not quite satisfied yet. I still have to test it for performance.

Comment: the performance is not the issue, if you want to display the names

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for my case. Maybe not the smartest but it works. There are probably better solutions. I don't know what influence the size of the data set will have on the performance. I still have to test this.

```
SELECT c.*, co.name as continent, l.name as language 
FROM countries c  
JOIN continents co ON co.id = c.continent_id 
JOIN languages l ON l.id = c.language_id
WHERE c.id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: so it is my solution with an added IN clause, you didn't mention before